# mysql innodb one file per table where each file locates in a different directory?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I need to  import a rather large db with 3 large tables onto a server with 2 hds(no raid), each with a capacity of 2TB.
each table's ibd data file is about 800GB, therefore I'm facing the challenge of spreading them across the disks.
When I say importing, I mean import from mysqldump file.

what can be done?

Comment: Seems like InnoDB doesn't allow that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are starting with an empty database, it's pretty easy to create the empty tables and then move one of the data files to a separate volume before importing the data. You should shut down the server while you move the file, and create a symlink in the original position pointing to the new path.

Here's a simple example to illustrate how this is done.

In MySQL:

```
-- create empty tables
use test;
create table table1(id int) engine = innodb;
create table table2(id int) engine = innodb;
create table table3(id int) engine = innodb;
```

At the terminal:

```
# shut down mysql server
service mysql stop

# move one of the innodb files to a new volume
mv -i /usr/local/mysql/data/test/table3.ibd /mnt3/mysql/test/data/.

# create a symlink so mysqld can use the standard path to find the file
ln -s /mnt3/mysql/test/data/table3.ibd /usr/local/mysql/data/test/table3.ibd

# start mysql server
service mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked people from [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/) and here's what Kristian Nielsen told me:

> --innodb-file-per-table and symlink the data files to the appropriate location (there may be a "cleaner" way, but this is what I know works)

Comment: but I would have to symlink each data file separately into a different location, symlink the file itself, not directory it resides in, is that possible?

Comment: symlink each data file, it is possible.